# Determine the galois group of this 6 degree polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Determine the Galois group of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
$f(x)=x^6+22 x^5-9 x^4+12 x^3-37 x^2-29 x-15$

This question comes from Johns Hopkins University Fall 2018 algebra qualifying.

I have found it is irreducible over rational numbers by wolfram, but have no idea how to show its irreducibility on examination(Maybe Eisentein's criterion,but there are so many terms to compute, and I think I do not have so many time to calculate on exam =_=).
The Galois group $G$ is a subgroup of $S_6$.  And $f$ has two real root and hence two pairs of conjugate complex roots. Module a pirime p may work, but there are still so many terms and irreducibility to verify.

Any quick method will be appreciated.

Comment: As I know the irreducible polynomials of degree $\le4$ in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ I can quickly show that this is irreducible modulo $2$ and hence irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ as well.
The polynomial has no less than four distinct roots modulo five (and an irreducible quadratic factor), so the Galois group has a 2-cycle. I'm less confident that I could *quickly* show with paper and pencil work that modulo three it has an irreducible quintic factor. Anyway, modulo $2$ and $3$ prove that the Galois group is doubly transitive, hence modulo $5$ data shows all the 2-cycles are in there, hence it's $S_6$.

Comment: Back in the day ('87, Notre Dame) the quals were oral exams, and you were supposed to work them out on the chalkboard. I'm not sure I would have managed this under such circumstances. Even in my prime :-)

Comment: There are just $3$ irreducible quadratic polynomials modulo $3$, namely $(x + k)^2 + 1$, $k \in \Bbb F_3$, so it wouldn't take *that* long to show check that $f$ has an irreducible quintic factor modulo $3$, but it would still take uncomfortably long for a qualifying exam, especially since you presumably don't know ahead of time that computing modulo $3$ will be useful!